# choosing the best index according to condition among three lists with different range of values in python

Tags: python

I have a dict with three keys which consists of a list with same length. For example, the key 'a' has a list with a length of 5 and consists values ranging from 0 to 6000. Similarly, key 'b' with a length of 5 has values ranging from 0 to 1.0. Finally key 'c' with the same length has values ranging from (1x1) to (2000x2000).

I have to select an index between 0 and 4 on the condition that values of 'a' cannot be lower than 200. Values of 'b' cannot be lower than 0.95. Then, choose the highest value of 'c' among the indices that meet these two conditions.

A dummy data would be as follows,

```
  index     a          b           c
    0      600       0.99      (100x105)
    1      150        1.0       (50x40)
    2      820       0.75      (500x480)
    3      500       0.96      (200x190)
    4      400       0.97      (120x110)
```

Here, according to the two conditions i can filter the indices to 0, 3 and 4. Among these three the biggest value of 'c' is of the index 3. So the answer is `3      500       0.96      (200x190)`

How do i select this in the most efficient way? I think i might need to use pandas. How can i do it using pandas? Also, how to do it in the most pythonic way?

I am relatively new to coding. I am having a hard time figuring it out.

edit:
a code snippet of the dict

```
{
'a' : [600, 150, 820, 500, 400]
'b' : [0.99, 1.0, 0.75, 0.96, 0.97]
'c' : [(100,105), (50,40), (500,480), (200,190), (120,110)]
}
```

Comment: Can you give a code snippet for your dict?

Comment: "I think I might need to use pandas". It can be done without pandas. But do you still want to do this only with pandas ?

Comment: I have edited the post with code snippet

Comment: No. i don't want to use pandas. In fact, i trying to do it with filter and numpy. Haven't succeeded yet.

Comment: Your tuples are looking like `(100,105),(50,40)` . Is that correct? Or should it be `(100,100), (50,50)`, etc? (In each tuple, will both elements be equal?)

Comment: Yes, it is correct. I am thinking of multiplying the values within the tuple to do it easily.

Comment: Suppose `dict['c']` has `[(1,0),(200,0),(-200,1)]`. Which of these 3 tuples should be considered the "maximum tuple"?

Comment: values inside the tuple are always positive. Sorry i forgot to mention that. And the two values inside the tuple is always close to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the data you have:

```
d = {'a':[600,150,820,500,400], 'b':[0.99,1.0,0.75,0.96,0.97], 'c':[(100,105),(50,40),(500,480),(200,190),(120,110)]}
a_thresh = 200
b_thresh = 0.95
```

This is one way of solving, making just **one pass** over the lists in the dictionary:

```
from operator import mul

list_len = len(d['a'])
found_i = 0
for i in range(list_len):
    if ((d['a'][i]>=a_thresh) and (d['b'][i]>=b_thresh) and 
        (mul(*d['c'][i]) > mul(*d['c'][found_i]))):
        found_i = i
print (found_i)
```

Output:

```
3
```

You can do this without importing and using the `mul()` function, of course. It is only make the loop condition to appear a little compact. The `mul()` is just for multiplying the two parts of a tuple. To do this without `mul()`, search and replace `(mul(*d['c'][3]) > mul(*d['c'][found_i]))` with the longer expression `((d['c'][3][0]*d['c'][3][1]) > (d['c'][found_i][0]*d['c'][found_i][1]))`

Comment: I had done the solution in this way before doing it in a one liner.

Comment: Ok, I was just wondering why you called the one-liner the "most efficient" way, when it isn't ?

Comment: Could you explain why doing it the way i did is not efficient. I was just trying to avoid for loop as i have heard list comprehensions are better than using for loops. I really have little ideas in case.

Comment: I wasn't saying it's **not efficient**. I was just saying that it can't be the "most efficient" if it makes 2 passes. BTW, a list comprehension, despite being a one-liner, will still use a loop to build its list. From a performance point of view, a list comprehension is nothing more and nothing less than a traditional `for`loop that has had some of its sections slightly re-arranged. This applies to your list comprehension also (the one that is passed as argument to `max()`)

Comment: Could you explain what '2 passes' or 'one pass' as a matter of fact means? Again i ask this as i have little idea about these things and i am new.

Comment: A "pass" over a list is just an english (non-technical) term that means visiting/accessing/checking each element of the list, from start to finish. Generally, to keep things efficient, one must avoid multiple passes over a long list, and do what one wants to do in as few passes as possible.

Comment: If I have a list of integers, and I invoke `index(23)` to find the position of 23, from the point of view performance, superficially, it might look like it's "loop-free", but internally, the `index()` function has to make a pass over the list to find the position of 23.

Comment: If I have a list of integers called `my_list`, and if I call `index(max(my_list))` to find the index of the maximum value, I am making **two** passes (behind the scenes). The `max()` function makes one pass to find the maximum value. It's return value is then passed to the `index()` function to find the position of the maximum value. That makes it two passes. That is what is happening in your solution.

Comment: @NazmusSakibAbIR: As a matter of fact, your one-liner solution makes **three** passes over the lists (and not two as I had mentioned earlier). The actual list comprehension makes one pass over the lists to construct a smaller list that meets the `a` condition and the `b` condition. This smaller list is passed to `max()`, which makes one pass over this smaller list to find the max value. The maximum value is then passed to `index()` which makes another pass over the smaller list. Though the 2nd and 3rd passes are over a smaller list, we do not in general know if they're only 10% smaller or 90%

Answer (score 2):

This is relatively straightforward with `numpy`, although the slightly odd format of column `c` provides an interesting twist.

```
import numpy as np

d = {
'a' : [600, 150, 820, 500, 400],
'b' : [0.99, 1.0, 0.75, 0.96, 0.97],
'c' : [(100,105), (50,40), (500,480), (200,190), (120,110)]
}

# Load as numpy arrays. 
d_np = {key: np.array(value) for key, value in d.items()}

# Create logical mask based on given requirements
mask = np.logical_and(d_np['a'] > 200, d_np['b'] > 0.95)

# Multiply 'c' along dimension 1
c_product = np.prod(d_np['c'], axis=1)

# Get index of maximum value. Note that this index is relative to masked array.
max_index_masked = np.argmax(c_product[mask])

# Get original 'c' value. Need to mask the array so that our indexing works.
max_value = d_np['c'][mask][max_index_masked]

# Get index relative to unmasked array
index = np.arange(d_np['c'].shape[0])[mask][max_index_masked]
print(index)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But the answer should be index 3 not the value of index 3. However, your answer pointed me to the right direction. If i add another line to your code: `np.where(d_np['c']==max_value)[0]` i get `array([3, 3])` which is pretty much what i needed. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Have amended the answer with another way to get the index.

Comment: @AndrewGuy: Liked the brevity with which you created `d_np` !

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution without numpy, using list slicing

```
    data = {
        'a' : [600, 150, 820, 500, 400],
        'b' : [0.99, 1.0, 0.75, 0.96, 0.97],
        'c' : [(100,105), (50,40), (500,480), (200,190), (120,110)]
    }
    select_a = [index_a for index_a in range(len(data['a'])) if data['a'][index_a] >=200]
    select_b = [index_b for index_b in select_a if data['b'][index_b]>=0.95]
    result = select_b[0]
    for index_c in select_b:
        if((data['c'][index_c][0]*data['c'][index_c][1])>(data['c'][result][0]*data['c'][result][1])):
            result = index_c
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {
'a' : [600, 150, 820, 500, 400],
'b' : [0.99, 1.0, 0.75, 0.96, 0.97],
'c' : [(100,105), (50,40), (500,480), (200,190), (120,110)]
}

print(list(map(lambda x : x[0]*x[1], d['c'])).index(max([d_lists[2][0]*d_lists[2][1] for i, d_lists in enumerate(zip(d['a'], d['b'], d['c'])) if d_lists[0] > 200 and d_lists[1] > 0.9])))
```

The output is 3.

Comment: This solution makes **two** passes over the length of the list. The first pass happens while obtaining the `max` value using the `for` loop of your list comprehension. The second pass over the list is for finding the `index` at which the `max` value occurs.

Comment: If you want a solution that makes a **single pass**, you can look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

My attempt at a Numpy solution. Tried to make it as readable as possible.

```
import numpy as np

d = {
    'a': [600, 150, 820, 500, 400],
    'b': [0.99, 1.0, 0.75, 0.96, 0.97],
    'c': [(100, 105), (50, 40), (500, 480), (200, 190), (120, 110)]
}

a = np.array([
    np.arange(len(d['a'])),
    d['a'],
    d['b'],
    np.prod(np.array(d['c']), axis=1)
])

a = a[:, a[1] >= 200]
a = a[:, a[2] >= .95]
a = a[:, np.argmax(a[3])]
index = int(a[0])

print('result:', d['a'][index], d['b'][index], d['c'][index])
```