# choose best index among two lists consisting values that has different range for each list python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists where each list consists of values with different range.
The lists have same length. 
For example,

```
list1 = [59.6613, 176.3425, 243.9645, 63.9865, 803.6346, 163.8992, 704.3893,
563.9846, 631.4968, 98.6483, 156.7823, 380.8432]
list2 = [27069, 9608, 12875, 35083, 7569, 8075, 6032, 10983, 7962, 43218,
3219, 9328]
```

for better readability:

```
index              list1              list2
  0               59.6613             27069
  1              176.3425              9608
  2              243.9645             12875
  3               63.9865             35083
  4              803.6346              7569
  5              163.8992              8075
  6              704.3893              6032
  7              563.9846             10983
  8              631.4968              7962
  9               98.6483             43218
 10              156.7823              3219
 11              380.8432              9328
```

In this case, the answer is index 7 since both the two values are not too low compared to the other values.
How do i make conditions that select this index?
I have tried selecting the index with conditions like this post [choosing the best index according to condition among three lists with different range of values in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55155491/choosing-the-best-index-according-to-condition-among-three-lists-with-different)

But the values will not always be over the threshold i have set. It can vary. Which makes this a lot harder for as i am a newbie.

edit:
I cannot set a threshold because if i set a threshold and none of the values can meet or surpass the threshold i am left with no data.
That is why i need to make a condition that dynamically chooses best index that has a value on the higher side of each list according to the set of values in each list. I am saying this because there can be cases where an index of list1 has high value but same index of list2 have a low value. In such case i cannot choose that index.

Comment: not clear how you define "not too low"

Comment: What is your threshold difference of "not too low"?

Comment: If i use threshold difference than i can just follow the link i have provided in the post. But i need to select an index regardless the value is on the higher side (for example 1000) or lower side (for example 50)

Answer (score 0):

You can filter all the elements which satisfy your thresholds using `filter`:

```
threshold1 = 300   # thrashold for list 1
threshold2 = 10000 # thrashold for list 2


list1 = [59.6613, 176.3425, 243.9645, 63.9865, 803.6346, 163.8992, 704.3893,
563.9846, 631.4968, 98.6483, 156.7823, 380.8432]
list2 = [27069, 9608, 12875, 35083, 7569, 8075, 6032, 10983, 7962, 43218,
3219, 9328]

zipped_lists = list(zip(list1, list2))


filtered_data = list(
    filter(
           lambda zipped_item: all((zipped_item[0] > threshold1, zipped_item[1] > threshold2)),
           zipped_lists)
)

try:
    print(zipped_lists.index(filtered_data[0]))
except IndexError:
    print('No data which satisfies condition')
```

Comment: I cannot set a threshold as there can be situations in which no value inside a list can meet the threshold. In which case, i am left with no answer. I have to choose the best index regardless the values in a list is low.